# How to put two param-values in one context-param in Spring?

Tags: spring, web.xml, spring-social, context-param

Problem: I have two `contextConfigLocation` parameters, one with `@Configuration` classes for spring-social-facebook and one with xml-file for app:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.communicator.core.social.facebook.config</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Both of them use one `param-name`, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is this part of a `web.xml`?

Comment: I thought it was a CSV. You can also create your own context config loader.

Comment: Why do you have two of `contextConfigLocation` ... is it supposed to be a list?

Answer (score 4):

You will be try this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml,
        com.communicator.core.social.facebook.config
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use white space to separate each parameter within `<param-value>` like this.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/spring/*.xml /WEB-INF/resources/module/*.xml /WEB-INF/resources/function/*.xml /WEB-INF/resources/bean/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

After test all answers, none works for me. I found the solution in this post [JSF2 how to specify more than one custom element library in web.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460643/jsf2-how-to-specify-more-than-one-custom-element-library-in-web-xml-file)

```
<param-value>com.communicator.core.social.facebook.config;/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet spec says that you can have only one value for any context parameter. So, you are left with going with delimited list only.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>Hosts</param-name>
  <param-value>ex1.com,ex2.com,.....</param-value>
</context-param>
```